# How to calculate the value of coefficients in Auto-regressive model?

Tags: c, statistics, time-series, forecasting

[image: ARMA equation]

How to calculate the co-efficients (phi1, phi2..) in the Auto -regression linear equation above?

Answer (score 1):

Please mention what software you are using? Assuming you are using R Studio:

```
summary(arima(x, order=c(1,0,0))$coefficients
```

Put your dataset in place of "x".

Comment: I'm not using R, i'm planning to write a program in C, that can forecast. So i would like to know if there is a mathematical way/formula to do it.

Comment: Please tag your question with C so people can understand what are you asking.